# Debug httpd process

Tags: gdb, dynamic-analysis

I'm attempting to inspect memory of an httpd binary compiled statically with openssl. When I list the httpd processes, I get:

```
$ ps aux|grep httpd
root     58539  0.0  0.7  75364  3740 ?        Ss   14:49   0:00 /opt/httpd/bin/httpd
daemon   58850  0.0  0.5 364328  2556 ?        Sl   14:58   0:00 /opt/httpd/bin/httpd
daemon   58914  0.0  0.5 364328  2548 ?        Sl   14:59   0:00 /opt/httpd/bin/httpd
daemon   58942  0.0  0.5 364328  2544 ?        Sl   14:59   0:00 /opt/httpd/bin/httpd
```

I then tried attaching to each of the processes individually and applying a breakpoint to the function I am trying to debug. However, the breakpoint never gets triggered, although I know the function is being called.  I assume this problem relates to something along the lines of httpd forking on a new process, but I'm a bit stuck on how to proceed. Is there a generic way to ensure my breakpoint is triggered even if the processes forks?

Comment: Assuming your httpd is apache, to debug something like this, it might be best to `service httpd stop` and `gdb httpd -X`. That way, httpd will serve requests, but never fork, which makes things much easier to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the worker model your apache is configured to use its likely a new worker is being spawned to handle your request if your bp isnt hitting. Like Guntram said you can [disable forking](https://httpd.apache.org/dev/debugging.html) and put httpd in debug mode by using the `-X` flag and starting gdb with:

```
gdb httpd -X
```

If for some reason you need to debug the multiple worker configured httpd you should use the gdb options `set follow-fork-mode ask` or `set follow-fork-mode child` if you know you'd like to follow all forks in advance. (https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Forks.html). This would also be considered the 'generic approach' and would apply to programs that don't allow you to run single process in the foreground.